# Why should I use Perl instead of Ruby/Python/etc?

Tags: perl

I love Ruby and have been using it for a few years to handle day-to-day scripting tasks. Lately however, I've had a number of people tell me that Perl is where it's at. I have nothing against Perl, but it seems like it's kind of fallen behind the times a bit.

However, that's probably just my perception, so I'm asking all of you, what makes Perl so great? I'm genuinely seeking information here; I'd like to understand why this language has such ardent followers.

Comment: Really, why should you? Just use what do you know better and fits your customers requirements. Many ppl tell me "Forget about C/C++, use .NET", but I can't because I program for Linux and they do not understand it :)

Comment: Well, it's good to have several tools in your toolbox. It's hard to choose the right tool for the job if you only have one tool.

Comment: Ideally you should know the basics of both and then try to find which one makes your development more productive, based on your own experience. Just make sure to ask StacOverflow for the "best practice" so you can compare just that (e.g. building web app in Perl sucks if you're stuck with 1995 frameworks, but Perl has a lot MORE than 1995 frameworks to build web apps with, which may not be obvious unless you ask about it).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I had to name one great strength of Perl, it's one word: CPAN.

Having worked with Ruby as well, I'd not say that Perl is necessarily better or worse, but definitely more mature. It is, after all, much older. However, it's not decrepit. It has plenty of modern stuff, e.g., Moose and the 5.10 and 5.12 updates have fixed a lot of problems that the ancient 5.0.x had.

(And if you're wondering: Perl 5 and Perl 6 are different languages. The similar name is an unfortunate mistake. Though Perl 5 does borrow ideas from Perl 6 and vice versa.)

Comment: I don't really bother with Python myself, but doesn't it now have a fairly massive arsenal of libraries that is a fair rival to CPAN?

Comment: @Nate C-K: Not sure as I haven't really worked with Python either. But even is so, CPAN is still a great strength (it just may not be exclusive).

Comment: @Nate C-K: CPAN is more than a massive arsenal of libraries, it's  one central repository, complete with a tool chain for working with dependencies.

Comment: @Nate: not really, if you consider standard libraries, then yes, python has the upper hand, but when it comes to CPAN (ie installing extra modules outside of the standard build) then I honestly believe there can be little competition as to the amount of resources available, in any interpreted language...

Comment: Python has pypi (http://pypi.python.org/pypi) with 12981 packages and a command line tool easy_install to fetch them while Perl has CPAN with 19185 packages.. 50% more than Python.

Comment: Are you not aware that Python has a repository of over 12,000 libraries that you can download? Really, you can claim that Perl has the best library selection (which is subjective), that it has the largest (objectively true), but that there is "little competition" is objectively false. On practically all fronts Perl is in retreat and Python is on the advance, that is some pretty serious competition. That's not my preference (I actually use Perl and not Python), but it is a fact.

Comment: @Spaceghost - those numbers are a not correct - see a recent blog entry in chromatic's "Modern Perl" blog dissecting the CPAN package numbers and difficulty in correctly making such comparisons.

Comment: I got those numbers from the front pages of CPAN and pypi .. to be realistic, they simply represent how many unique package names exist in the different systems and mot much more.

Comment: The numbers are absolutely correct, inasmuch as Spaceghost does not represent them as anything other than package counts from those particular sites. However, it's also true that they may not represent the true number of packages that are available. Probably more important is that some packages (e.g. Python's Django or Perl's DBI) are so hugely useful that they alone might determine your choice of language.

Comment: @DVK thanks for the hint. I took a look at the blog entry (http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/12/counting-modules.html) and was stunned to discover that cpan.org (where I got the Perl module count, not CPAN) only lists approximately 20% of all Perl modules available from cpan.  If I had used search.cpan.org I would have got a number closer to 89332. Wow.

Comment: I wonder how many are actually usable.

Comment: Having a huge library of packages does not make one language better than the next as these libraries are artifacts of time. They are merits of the users, not innate properties of the language that would make one chose it over the next language. "Perl has more packages than x, therefore it we will use it" is a terrible way of putting it and tells ***nothing*** about what is great about **Perl**. This answer is incorrect and does not address the question. --- Compare the answer to "You should use Debian over Gentoo because Debian has more packages." *Please...*

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин If you're comparing languages as art, sure (if you ignore using how both Perl & Ruby extend the language with libraries). But if you're comparing languages to use to solve problems, then "is there a library that helps?" an important question. And for Perl the answer is almost always yes. (I'm tempted to suggest that given the superiority of in-person conversation [ability to read body language, clarify immediately, etc.], you yell your programming questions out at a street corner, instead of on SO; the presence of qualified programmers on SO is not an innate property of SO)

Comment: Not sure why you think that I'm yelling. I didn't mean to pick a fight. Thanks for clarifying your opinion.

Answer (score 23):

I know a good handful of hackers who left Perl to go to Ruby. Python is obviously a nice language too. I am neither saying nor implying anything against either.

### Pros for Perl 5

- Since about 2005 or so Perl has been in a fairly dramatic renaissance in both CPAN and core releases. Perl 6 has helped drive this by sending concepts like role-oriented OO back. Strawberry Perl has made Perl hacking on Windows more like *nix.
- The [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/) is huge, still growing, and most of the more widely used authors/teams are responsive to bugfixes. Most popular Perl modules are tested widely and well. CPAN testers recently sent their 10 millionth test report.
- Many of the big kits have good communities associated where expert help is available quickly.
- The tool chain has become very flexible.

  - The combination of [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::perlbrew), [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local::lib), and [cpanminus](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?cpanm) lets users (even without root) have an arbitrary number of perl versions and libraries accessible on the same box.
- Many of things that Java, Ruby, Python do right come back to Perl and with facility. For example–

  - [KinoSearch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?KinoSearch) is [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) but even faster by some benchmarks.
  - [Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst) is [Rails](http://www.rubyonrails.org/) but more flexible. It’s a completely agnostic C with regards to the M and V.
  - [Plack](http://plackperl.org) is Python’s [WSGI](http://wsgi.org/) + Ruby’s [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/).
- It’s as fast and personal or readable and robust as you want it to be.

  - A short one-liner can edit every HTML file in your tree when you’re in a hurry to fix something.
  - A clear and robust program with error reporting, logging, and feedback built on any of the 6 or 7 suitable HTML/XML packages could do the same for a client.
- [Perlmonks](http://perlmonks.org). Though there are notable exceptions, the Perl community is generally friendly, helpful, and positive.
- There are quite a few good Perl jobs waiting to be filled. The back and forth between the high level languages has left oodles of Perl in the wild without a matching crop of Perl-centric devs. (I get 5-7 cold calls from recruiters a year.)
- It’s fun. In quotes: “[Perl has the happiest users](http://blog.doloreslabs.com/2009/05/the-programming-language-with-the-happiest-users/).” I can’t speak to the scientific nature of that but I can say I **only** program today because Perl exists. Many other Perl hackers share this stupid giddiness for the language.

Keep in mind it’s not a zero sum game. The more languages you can wield, the better.

Comment: +1 for all the excellent points especially the last paragraph.  I would suggest adding an extra bullet for "Breadth of good quality CPAN code" - you addressed stability more explicitly but not the chances of finding a solution for any given specific problem.

Comment: Although I love Perl, these are all secondary considerations. Use Perl when it does what *you* need, not when it does something that someone else needs. If Ruby is doing it for you, don't switch.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph: I didn't start programming with Perl (I started with Basic and C), but Perl was the first language with which I was able to really accomplish useful, non-trivial tasks. That was crucial in keeping me interested in programming as a career rather than just messing around.

Comment: +1 for reminding me why Perl keeps pulling me back! Somehow there is nothing I can NOT do with Perl.

Comment: Also, Larry Wall's Programming in Perl is, IMO, one of the all time great programming books. Even if it is out of date now.

Answer (score 5):

CPAN.

The syntax of Perl is sometimes painful to look at but it is available on Unix machines everywhere and with the command line access to the huge number of packages in CPAN  (which can also be accessed via browser), Perl is the de facto standard because of its broad applicability and availability.

Comment: If someone presents you with Perl code painful to look at, shoot the messenger. One doesn’t blame the paint for a poorly crafted piece of artwork.

Comment: @tchrist: I wrote another response and humbly apologise.

Comment: Reading Perl is a skill and it doesn't help that Perl is, sometimes, difficult to read. After all, as a wise man once said "Only perl can parse Perl"

Comment: It's not the syntax. It's more about one of Perl's design principles: There is more than one way to do it! It makes the language more beautiful but the way literature is. Sometimes you  see a piece of mean but beautiful code that could be written in a much easier-to-read way, but then it wasn't beautiful as much.

Comment: Perl's reference syntax is a huge eyesore, and it's so vital to the language there are tons of things that you can't reasonably do without using it. It's also a fact that Perl has a more problematic syntax than most other languages and is thus unparseable by most (all?) conventional compiler generation tools (which is what Spaceghost is referring to). It seems to me that Larry Wall tried many interesting experiments with Perl's syntactic design, and some work well but some really don't.

Answer (score 2):

These days, IMO the main reason to use Perl is that you can be pretty confident that just about any UNIX system will have it available, even on the sparser commercial UNIX distros.

Also, it has some features that make it work very conveniently with the UNIX shell and filesystem. Perl one-liners are convenient in shell scripting when you need a little more power.

If you're not on a UNIX machine then there's probably little advantage over more modern scripting languages.

Comment: The fact that language is 'newer' doesn't necessarily mean it is more 'modern' as you put it. Regardless of the platform it still all comes down to a matter of preference though.

Comment: I didn't say newer language, I said more modern; obviously a newer but less modern language would be a poor choice. And no, it is not just a matter of preference as there are objective differences between the language platforms. For example, many recent pieces of software expose an API in Python but not in Perl, so Perl is obviously not a good choice there.

Comment: Blender, Dia, GEdit, Battle for Wesnoth AI. For the SDL, there is SDL_Perl, but Python has PyGame which takes support a step further. WxWidgets has a Perl API, but the Python API is supported as the non-C++ interface of choice; the documentation is subtitled "A portable C++ and Python GUI toolkit". Do you want to do scripting in a .NET app? IronPython is probably what you want. I guess ActiveState is doing a Perl on .NET, but it doesn't seem to have nearly the support behind it that .NET does.

Comment: @Nat - re: Battle for Wesnoth, that's just ESR's circa 2000 "I hatez on perlz" attitude (read his "why I use Python" article :). I have a feeling that ESR might have changed his evaluation had he re-tried the same experiment (writing larger-than 100 LOC program in Perl) using circa 2011 Modern Perl.

Comment: @Nat - curiously enough, when I tried to google for wesnoth Python AI stuff to see how difficult it'd be to have a Perl interface, I stumbled upon this: **"Note: Starting from version 1.5.11 PythonAI support was removed from wesnoth"** (http://wiki.wesnoth.org/ReferencePythonAPI). I wasn't able to easily find the reasoning behind this. Anyway, the rest of your list is valid :)

Comment: Ah, well, I just threw that one in to add another bullet point :) Actually any script language doesn't seem all that appropriate for AI (real AI, at least) because it's an application where performance is critical. (BTW, have you ever noticed how many of ESR's articles contain references to him being a master hacker? A bit of insecurity there?)

Answer (score 2):

First of all I love Python and Ruby as well. In fact I think anything you can do in anyone of the 3 languages you can do in the other just as easily.

CPAN however is a big advantage. There are not many times I find myself looking for a specific general functionality and not finding a module for it. 
The greatest thing for me is however is that I can do absolutely everything I want, quickly, and in 10 different ways if I like, but maybe that's just because Perl is my 'mother tongue'.

Anyway, I think it depends on what you want to do. If you want to create a scalable website or web application with all the plumbing (authentication, authorization, session tracking, database ORM, etc, etc) taken care of, it can be done in Perl, but the hassle is not worth it. Go with Python (Django) or Ruby (Rails 3.0 rocks) then.

Good luck and watch out fire setting of flamewars with this subject, this kind of stuff get seriously get you hurt ;)

Rob

Comment: can you please provide a reference for the fact that creating anything more than an elementary web app is harder with Catalyst vs. RubyOnRails? Based on this resource, the hassle is LESS on Catalyst side: http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/Catalyst_vs_Ruby_on_Rails

Comment: It seems like you're comparing programming in raw Perl (or maybe Perl/FastCGI) to using an established framework in another language. Obviously a framework gives you a big advantage, but Perl has well-established frameworks as well.

Comment: Hi DVK and Nate - I have used CGI::Application quite a bit, in fact I am now using it for a large ExtJS Direct driven app. Catalyst I have tried out in the past but at first touch it felt a bit uncomfortable. What I like about Perl is that I can decide myself how to do it. Catalyst felt (apart from the horrible installation process, maybe thats better now) a bit more restrictive. Anyhow, I feel strong about 'using what works for you'. In the end we are all trying to solve a problem, the tools that best helps you to do so you should choose.

Comment: BTW, has Catalyst been changed over the last 2 years? if so I will maybe give it a go again. I have tried out a lot of different programming languages and frameworks, but somehow Perl keeps pulling me back like a sort of Hotel California :)

Comment: Never mind, found the Catalyst wiki. Think I'll do my next project in Catalyst :)